Fragment did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView()
In an activity, I have got two separate fragments (for simplicity let say fragment x and fragment y). This is how I'm navigating using navigation graphs:

x -> y (Button) x <- y (System Back button, Action Bar Back Button)

There is a button on y (say z), which when clicked shows you a snackbar. But when I go back by using either of the two back buttons, and then again navigate to y from x, and when I again click z, it crashes my app giving me the following error:
Error:
Fragment y did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView().

This is how I call the snackbar:
snackbarUtil.showErrorSnackbar(strings[0], strings[1], requireView(), requireActivity());

This is how I navigate back:
 requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (isEnabled()) {
                setEnabled(false);
                navigationUtil.navigateBack();

            }
        }
    });

and this:
requireActivity().addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                navigationUtil.navigateBack();
                return true;
            }
            return y.super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
    });

Fragment Y:
 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    navigationUtil = new NavigationUtil("viewID", requireActivity(), R.id.authFragmentView, null);
    textAppearAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireActivity(), R.anim.text_appear);
    slideUpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireActivity(), R.anim.slide_up_entry);
    getMediaUtil = new GetMediaUtil(requireActivity(), requireActivity().getActivityResultRegistry());
    getLifecycle().addObserver(getMediaUtil);

    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (isEnabled()) {
                setEnabled(false);
                navigationUtil.navigateBack();

            }
        }
    });
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 

    this.binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_y, container, false);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(requireActivity());
    yViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory()).get(YViewModel.class);
    yViewModel.setViewModelStoreOwner(requireActivity());
    yViewModel.setActivity(requireActivity());

    return binding.getRoot();


}


Add code of Fragment Y with question .

what code of y? the button click? onCreate? onCreateView?

please share oncreate and oncreateview

are you using viewbinding ?

No, I am using data binding

I see you are passing a view ID to NavigationUtil class . Do not do that .. A class which is not lifecycle aware will end up causing memory leeks and other problems as well.. Also you said your app crash on click and i do not see any click listeners or snack bar in your code  above .

Okay, then what would you suggest for navigationUtil?

I am calling the method with the help of two way data binding, directly from xml file. and then in that method, I check for errors, if there is an error then I show the snackbar
